# Help ordering custom query by Title, Ascending

Tags: custom-post-types, query, get-posts, order

I have an old project (custom post type query) that needs an alteration and my memory/skill level is lacking for what to do. With the code below, **I'm needing to return the first query in alphabetical order, by title.** Using `orderby => title` and `order => asc` (line 9 and 10) has no effect. It works in the second query (lines 39 & 40), though. I had a colleague help me set this up originally but he is not available to help with this tweak. Any help by the SE community would be appreciated.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <h1>Properties in <?php the_terms('', 'region');?></h1>
        <?php 
            $queried_object = get_queried_object();
            $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'rental',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order'   => 'ASC',
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'region',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => ".$queried_object->slug."
                                    )
                                )
                        );
          $query = get_posts( $args );
          $property=array();
           if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
             <?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'property', array("fields" => "ids"));
            foreach($term_list as $id)
            {
              array_push($property,$id);
            }
            ?>
             <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query();
                $property=array_unique($property); 
                foreach($property as $ids)
                {$terms=get_term_by('id', $ids, 'property');
                ?><h1><?php echo $terms->name ?></h1><?php 
                ?>
                <?php
                  $args1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'rental',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $ids

             ),
           array('taxonomy' => 'region',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => ".$queried_object->slug.")
          )
        );
        $query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
              foreach($query1->posts as $posts)
              {
                $region_array=get_the_terms($posts->ID,'region');
                $property_array = get_the_terms( $posts->ID, 'property' );
                $bedrooms_array = get_the_terms(  $posts->ID, 'bedrooms' );
                $bathrooms = get_the_terms(  $posts->ID, 'bathrooms' );
                $views = get_the_terms(  $posts->ID, 'view' );

                $rows = get_field('rental_images',$posts->ID); // get all the rows
                $first_row = $rows[0]; // get the first row
                $first_row_image = $first_row['rental_images-image' ]; // get the sub field value 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $first_row_image, 'thumbnail' );
              ?>
                <div class="rental">
                  <div class="pic">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($posts->ID);?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" /></a>
                  </div><!-- .pic -->
                  <div class="text">
                        <ul>
                            <li><?php echo $posts->post_title ?></li>
                                                <?php 
                            if($bedrooms_array!='' )
                            {$i=0;
                              ?><li>Bedrooms:<?php
                            foreach($bedrooms_array as $bed)
                            {
                              if($i==0)
                              {
                                $i=1;
                              ?>
                               <?php echo $bed->name; ?>
                            <?php }
                            else
                            {
                              echo ", ".$bed->name;
                            }
                             }
                            ?></li><?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }?>
                                                 <?php
                            if($bathrooms!='')
                            {?><li>Bathrooms: <?php
                            $i=0;
                            foreach($bathrooms as $bath)
                            {
                              if($i==0)
                              {
                                echo $bath->name;
                                $i=1;
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                echo ", ".$bath->name;
                              }}?></li><?php
                            }?>
                                              <?php 
                            if($views!='')
                            {?><li>View: <?php
                            $i=0; 
                            foreach($views as $v)
                            {
                              if($i==0)
                              {
                                $i=1;
                                echo $v->name;  
                              }
                              else
                              {
                              echo ", ".$v->name;
                              }
                            }?></li><?php }?>
                                        </ul>
                            </div><!-- .text -->
                        </div><!-- .rental -->
              <?php  }
              }?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up a bit on how The Loop works in Wordpress:
https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

And how the WP_Query class:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

I am assuming your only want 2 loops, at the moment your have 3.

1. On line 19, which stores its posts in a var $query then does nothing.
2. On line 21, which is your main unaltered loop.
3. On line 54, which your colleague helps you with? Seems to be working.

So what you need to do is pass the arguments from your first loop to your second loop instead.

You can do this by making a new WP_Query like you did on line 53.

```
$query = get_posts( $args ); // line 19
```

becomes:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and Loop through the results using the have_posts() function.

```
if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); // line 21
```